# What is the origin of "Core Assessment" for freshman university classes?

Tags: assessment

As a math faculty in a public institution in TX, USA, I am supposed to conduct a "Core Assessment" for most of my freshman classes. This typically entails an assignment to be completed by students. There is a very lengthy rubric to be used to grade and assess student performance. Then a tally is submitted through a chain of command in university.

Where/when did this practice originate? Who sets the standard and the rubric? What was the philosophy behind it? What is done with the data?

Edits:

Seen mostly in Texas,
[Texas Higher Education Coordinating Board](https://www.highered.texas.gov/our-work/supporting-our-institutions/institutional-resources/transfer-resources/texas-core-curriculum/),
[Texas A&M](https://assessment.tamu.edu/core),
[U Texas](https://ugs.utexas.edu/core-assessment)

But also nationally and at different levels
[U Nevada, Reno](https://www.unr.edu/assessment/core)
[A K-12 version](https://learning.ccsso.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Math_Standards1.pdf)

Related and of interest

[U Wisconsin, Milwaukee](https://uwm.edu/academicaffairs/wp-content/uploads/sites/32/2019/04/Guide.pdf)

Comment: This document cites some specific standards’ “chapter and verse” as to what they are supposed to achieve and why: https://www.lamar.edu/planning-assessment/_files/documents/core-curriculum-assessment-committee.pdf

Comment: @Steve - that link goes to a one page listing of the lucky committee memebers.

Comment: @JonCuster The first line describes the “charge” of the committee — to comply with two standards: requirements of THECB Core Curriculum reporting and SACSCOC 8.2.b. I have no idea what those are but at least it’s a lead for someone else with more interest in going down this rabbit hole. These appear to be related to accreditation requirements.

Comment: A brief overview of THECB Core Curriculum is at https://reportcenter.highered.texas.gov/agency-publication/miscellaneous/elements-of-the-texas-core-curriculum/

Comment: Assessment of student learning (distinct from "grades") is widely practiced in higher education in the US.  It's required as a condition of accreditation by the regional accreditation bodies.  It's also very common for individual states to have general education core requirements that are to be met by all students with an assessment of those learning outcomes required of the institutions.